# Почему DataView вызывает Reset при Merge?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Собственно сабж

когда делаю так

```
var view = theDataTable.DefaultView;
theDataTable.Merge(theDataTable2)
```

то DataView генерирует в самом конце объединения событие `ListChanged`, в котором `e.ListChangedType == Reset`. В результате и контрол, который привязан к вьюхе, делает полный сброс. Как с этим бороться? Можно ли сделать мерджинг так, чтобы он протекал построчно, выдавая события добавления строк?

Comment: Собсна, обычно один `Reset` намного дешевле N операций `Add\Remove`

Comment: Как вариант - сделать собственный `Merge`, который как раз таки будет выполнять обычные `Add`, `Remove`.

Comment: @Monk, конечно дешевле... Только я бы сам хотел выбирать, чем пожертвовать )

Comment: @Monk, а вот RejectChanges не вызывает Reset, а поэлементно удаляет/добавляет все строки

Comment: Потому что это другой метод и предназначен для отмены изменений.

Comment: @Monk, так изменений тоже бывает много. Особенно после операции Merge, при которой он делает Reset. Вам не кажется это нелогичным? .NET логичен, как правило. Посему мне думается, что должен быть способ смержить поэтапно. А писать свой метод накладно. Я ведь не знаю всего, что он делает. Кроме строк ведь у таблиц есть и другие параметры.